# Issue in posting a comment

Tags: 7, comments, database

When I post a comment, I get the following error on Drupal 7:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'comment-28-0-0-und' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {field_data_comment_body} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, comment_body_value, comment_body_format) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => comment [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 28 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 28 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => comment_node_multi_discussion_theme [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => test [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 451 of /ftphome/dev_itf_events/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).

What could be the cause?

Comment: Have you manually deleted any database rows or truncated any tables? Have you recently copied over any development environment databases to your production site or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to remove the row from field_data_comment_body table where entity id is 28 ..